# Enumerator#each Restarts Sequence

Tags: ruby, sequence, enumerator

I'm surprised that Enumerator#each doesn't start off at the current position in the sequence.

```
o = Object.new

def o.each
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
end

e = o.to_enum
puts e.next
puts e.next
e.each{|x| puts x}
# I expect to see 1,2,3 but I see 1,2,1,2,3
# apparently Enumerator's each (inherited from Enumerable) restarts the sequence!
```

Am I doin' it wrong? Is there a way to maybe construct another Enumerator (from e) that will have the expected each behavior?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you expect to see 1,2,3 - you will see `1,2,1,2,3` if you start with e.g. an array `[1,2,3]` instead of your example, so your object construction is fine, but if you do `e.each{|x| next if x < 3; puts x; }`, it would only output 3 in the loop. `next` and `each` are not interacting in the way you expect.

Comment: @NeilSlater I expect #each to take the Enumerator state into account because, well, it's a method on the Enumerator. I am surprised that the Enumerator#each is essentially giving me the same behavior as the original Object's #each did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing it wrong, that's just not the semantics defined for [`Enumerator#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each).  You could make a derivative enumerator that only iterates from current position to end:

```
class Enumerator
  def enum_the_rest
    Enumerator.new { |y| loop { y << self.next } }
  end
end

o = Object.new
def o.each
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
end

e = o.to_enum
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
e.next
=> 1
e2 = e.enum_the_rest
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
e2.each { |x| puts x }
=> 2
=> 3
```

And, BTW, `each` doesn't restart the sequence, it just always runs over the entire span. Your enumerator still knows where it is in relation to the next `next` call.

```
e3 = o.to_enum
e3.next
=> 1
e3.next
=> 2
e3.map(&:to_s)
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
e3.next
=> 3
```

Comment: Would this be even a little better: `class Enumerator; def each_remaining; return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?; loop{ yield self.next};end;end`

Answer (score 2):

[`Enumerator#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [`Enumerator#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) work on the object differently. Per the documentation for `#each` (emphasis mine):

> Iterates over the block **according to how this Enumerable was constructed**. If no block is given, returns self.

So `#each` always behaves based on the original setup, not on the current internal state. If you quickly peak at the source you'll see that `rb_obj_dup` is called to setup a new enumerator.

Comment: Interestingly, enumerators don't seem support `dup` once they have advanced from the start: `e=o.to_enum; e.dup` works without complaint, `e=o.to_enum; e.next; e.dup` gets "TypeError: can't copy execution context"

Comment: @dbenhur Yeah, I don't have a good grasp on why that would be. My guess would be that it's probably an issue with the fiber instantiated under the hood. The behavior for `dup` may be ambiguous once you've called `next`. Do you create a new fiber at the same point, did you just want a dup of the original state, etc?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that documentation @AaronK. I had read that but you made me read it again and now I understand it. I still think it's wrong for Enumerator#each to fail to take into account the Enumerator state. I would be happier if the behavior and the doc changed :)